# Is it possible to fold <*> in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I want to realize something like

```
fun1 f a_ziplist
```

for example

```
getZipList $ (\x y z -> x*y+z) <$> ZipList [4,7] <*> ZipList [6,9] <*> ZipList [5,10]

f = (\x y z -> x*y+z) 
ziplist = [[4,7],[6,9],[5,10]]
```

To do this, I want to recursively apply <*> like

```
foldx (h:w) = h <*> foldx w
foldx (w:[]) = w
```

but it seems impossible to make <*> recursive.

Comment: What type signature should your desired function have?

Comment: The question is not clear. First of all, `fun1 f a_ziplist` could be anything. Secondly, the example doesn't make any sense: what is the relationship between the first expressions, `f` and `ziplist`? Third, `foldx` requires a type signature or a description (what do you mean with "make `<*>` recursive"?).

Comment: If the `ziplist` argument has to be a plain list, it looks impossible. This is because `fun1 f [a1,...,an]` must be well typed for every `n`, hence `f` must be a function type taking at least `n` arguments for every `n`, hence infinitely many. However, it you instead use a GADT like `List (a :: *) (n :: Nat)` where the `n` appears in the type as a type-level natural, then it is possible to build something like `fun1 :: Apply n a (m b) -> List (m a) n -> m b`.

Answer (score 4):

Let's play with the types in ghci, to see where they carry us.

```
λ import Control.Applicative
```

The type of `(<*>)`

```
λ :t (<*>)
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

The type of `foldr`:

```
λ :t Prelude.foldr
Prelude.foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

Perhaps we could use `(<*>)` as the function that is passed as the first parameter of `foldr`. What would be the type?

```
λ :t Prelude.foldr (<*>)
Prelude.foldr (<*>) :: Applicative f => f a -> [f (a -> a)] -> f a
```

So it seems that it takes an initial value in an applicative context, and a list of functions in an applicative context, and returns another applicative.

For example, using `ZipList` as the applicative:

```
λ getZipList $ Prelude.foldr (<*>) (ZipList [2,3]) [ ZipList [succ,pred], ZipList [(*2)] ]
```

The result is:

```
[5]
```

I'm not sure if this is what the question intended, but it seems like a natural way to `fold` using `(<*>)`.

Answer (score 4):

If the `ziplist` argument has to be a plain list, it looks impossible. This is because `fold f [a1,...,an]` must be well typed for every `n`, hence `f` must be a function type taking at least `n` arguments for every `n`, hence infinitely many.

However, if you use a GADT list type, in which values expose their length as a type-level natural you can achieve something similar to what you want.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, TypeFamilies, GADTs #-}

import Control.Applicative

-- | Type-level naturals
data Nat = Z | S Nat

-- | Type family for n-ary functions
type family   Fn (n :: Nat) a b
type instance Fn Z     a b = b
type instance Fn (S n) a b = a -> Fn n a b

-- | Lists exposing their length in their type
data List a (n :: Nat) where
  Nil :: List a Z
  Cons :: a -> List a n -> List a (S n)

-- | General <*> applied to a list of arguments of the right length
class Apply (n :: Nat) where
   foldF :: Applicative f => f (Fn n a b) -> List (f a) n -> f b

instance Apply Z where
   foldF f0 Nil = f0

instance Apply n => Apply (S n) where
   foldF fn (Cons x xs) = foldF (fn <*> x) xs

test :: [(Integer,Integer,Integer)]
test = foldF (pure (,,)) (Cons [10,11] (Cons [20,21] (Cons [30,31] Nil)))
-- Result: [(10,20,30),(10,20,31),(10,21,30),(10,21,31)
--         ,(11,20,30),(11,20,31),(11,21,30),(11,21,31)]
```

Answer (score 2):

In general folding `(<*>)` is tricky because of types, as others have mentioned.  But for your specific example, where your ziplist elements are all of the same type, you can use a different method and make your calculation work with a small change to `f` to make it take a list argument instead of single elements:

```
import Data.Traversable
import Control.Applicative

f = (\[x,y,z] -> x*y+z) 
ziplist = [[4,7],[6,9],[5,10]]

fun1 f l = getZipList $ f <$> traverse ZipList l
```

It's even possible to achieve this with just `Data.List` and `Prelude` functions:

```
fun1 f = map f . transpose
```

Answer (score 0):

> To do this, I want to recursively apply `<*>` like
>
> ```
> foldx (h:w) = h <*> foldx w
> foldx (w:[]) = w
> ```
>
> but it seems impossible to make <*> recursive.

I think you're getting confused over left- vs. right-associativity.  danidiaz reformulates this in terms of `foldr (<*>)`, which is quite useful for this analysis.  The documentation gives [a useful definition of `foldr` in terms of expansion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr):

```
foldr f z [x1, x2, ..., xn] == x1 `f` (x2 `f` ... (xn `f` z) ...)
```

So applying that to your case:

```
foldr (<*>) z [x1, x2, ..., xn] == x1 <*> (x2 <*> ... (xn <*> z) ...)
```

Note the parens. `<*>` is left-associative, so the `foldr` expansion is different from:

```
x1 <*> x2 <*> ... <*> xn <*> z == ((... (x1 <*> x2) <*> ...) <*> xn) <*> z
```

---

Let's think also a bit more about what `foldr (<*>)` means.  Another way of thinking of this is to rewrite it just slightly:

```
flip (foldr (<*>)) :: Applicative f :: [f (a -> a)] -> f a -> f a
```

Types of the form `(a -> a)` are often called **endomorphisms**, and they form a monoid, with composition as the operation and `id` as the identity.   There's a `newtype` wrapper in `Data.Monoid` for these:

```
newtype Endo a = Endo { appEndo :: a -> a }

instance Monoid (Endo a) where
    mempty = id
    mappend = (.)
```

This gives us yet another way to think of `foldr (<*>)`, by formulating it in terms of `Endo`:

```
toEndo :: Applicative f => f (a -> a) -> Endo (f a)
toEndo ff = Endo (ff <*>)
```

And then what `foldr (<*>)` does, basically, is reduce this monoid:

```
foldrStar :: Applicative f => [f (a -> a)] -> Endo (f a)
foldrStar fs = mconcat $ map toMonoid fs
```

Answer (score 0):

what you have is equivalent to `zipWith3 (\x y z -> x*y+z) [4,7] [6,9] [5,10]`.

it's impossible to `foldl` the `<*>` (and you do need `foldl` as `<*>` associates *to the left*) because `foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a` i.e. it's **the same `a`** in `a -> b -> a`, but when you apply your ternary function on first list of numbers, you get a list of binary functions, and then unary functions at the next step, and only finally, numbers (all different types, then):

```
>> let xs = map ZipList [[4,7],[6,9],[5,10]]    
>> getZipList $ pure (\x y z -> x*y+z) <*> (xs!!0) <*> (xs!!1) <*> (xs!!2)
[29,73]
>> foldl (<*>) (pure (\x y z -> x*y+z)) xs

<interactive>:1:6:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: b = a -> b
      Expected type: f (a -> b)
      Inferred type: f b
    In the first argument of `foldl', namely `(<*>)'
    In the expression: foldl (<*>) (pure (\ x y z -> x * y + z)) xs

>> :t foldl
foldl ::                   ( a         ->  b  ->  a ) -> a -> [b] -> a
>> :t (<*>)
(<*>) :: (Applicative f) => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b    -- f (a -> b) = f b
```

The answer by chi addresses this, but *the arity is fixed* (for a particular code). In effect, what that answer really does is defining (a restricted version of) `zipWithN` (well, here, when used with the `ZipList` applicative - obviously, it works with any applicative in general) for any `N` (but just for the `a -> a -> a -> ... -> a` type of functions), whereas e.g.

```
zipWith7 :: (a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f -> g -> h) -> 
            [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [d] -> [e] -> [f] -> [g] -> [h]
```

(in other words, `zipWith3 (,,) [10,11] ([20,21]::[Integer]) ([30,31]::[Int])` [works](http://ideone.com/oOyrvo)).